# Are local git branches ever deleted automatically when their remote branch is removed?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Using DevOps, I've noticed that when merging (completing) an accepted pull-request, my local branch is not removed even when I select to delete the branch as part of the completion action. I have made sure I fetched and I see the remote branch disappear, but the local branch remains.

I'm not sure if this is standard Git behaviour or specific to DevOps. Is my local branch usable - could I 're-push' it for example - or should I simply delete it manually?

Comment: Short answer : yes you could repush it any time. No it won't ever be garbage collected if you don't explicitly delete it.

Comment: This is standard behaviour. I would be kinda annoyed if git deleted my local branches just because the remote branch disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(TLDR) The short answer is **no**.

The slightly longer answer is that git is not a client/server system. It is a local-only version control system (hard-disk only) with a peer-to-peer synchronization added on. When you pull or fetch or push you are comparing your repository with another peer repository.

Git was deliberately designed serverless so that all git repository are the complete full repository.

The fact that we declare certain repo (eg github or DevOps) as the single repository that all developers on a project sync to is just human convention. From git's point of view all repo are the complete repo for a specific developer. Note again that the convention is just what is agreed between humans. There is nothing in the git protocol that makes any repo more "central" than any other.

Comment: One interesting example of how peer-to-peer git is that I almost never see people do anymore but I used to do a lot is that you can pull and push directly from other developer's machines. I used to do this when peer programming with someone. Nowdays we'd push a branch to github/gitlab to work together